# How to parse json if the same key can have different types?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing

How to parse json if the same key can have different types in Dart?

And depending on the types, I have to return different data models.

Here is an example of the json I get:

```
{
 "choosen": {},
},

{
"choosen": {
      "Options1":: "m0v38u458yub8ea3"
    },
},

{
"choosen": {
      "Options1": {
        "address": {
          "key1": "45g4gcbc12b8ea3"
        },
      }
    },
},

{
"choosen": {
      "Options2": {
        "address1": {
          "key1": "cbc12fda5f0e82",
        "token": "23423ffdsb6cbc12fda5f0e82"
        },
      }
    },
},

{
"choosen": {
      "Options2": {
        "address2": {
          "SelectItem1": {
            "key1": "04n1pdgnfmefgngyyfz6jzfccgb"
          }
        },
      },
},`
```

I understand that this can be done using the dynamic type... But maybe there is still a more correct solution?

I've tried to do similar things:

```
class Option1 extends Optios{
  final ChoosenOptionKeyNames keyName;
  final ChoosenOptionKeys  key;
  Option1 ({required this.keyName, required this.key});

  factory Option1.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    final ChoosenOptionKeyNames keyName= ChoosenOptionKeyNames.values.byName(json.keys.first);
    final ChoosenOptionKeys key;
    switch (keyName) {
      case keyName.Key1:
        key= Key1.fromJson(json[keyName.name]);
        break;
      case keyName.Key2:
        key = Key2.fromJson(json[keyName]);
        break;
    }

    return Option1 (keyName: json.keys.first, key: key);
  }
}

enum ChoosenOptionKeyNames {
  Key1,
  Key2;
}

class ChoosenOptionKeys {
}

class Key2 extends ChoosenOptionKeys {
  final ChoosenOptionKeyNames key;
  Ln({required this.key});

  factory Key2.fromJson(String str) =>
      Ln(key: keyClass.fromMap()););
}

class Key1 extends ChoosenOptionKeys {
  final ChoosenOptionKeyNames key;
  Key1({required this.key});

  factory Key1.fromJson(String str) =>
      Key1 (key: keyClass.fromStr());     (and so on...)
}

class keyClass {
  keyClass.fromStr(){
    ...
  };
  keyClass.fromMap(){
    ...
  };
}
```

and so on and on...

Comment: What about using this json as raw Map<String, dynamic> instead of object? It can be much easier. Anyway, if you really need to have an object, you can check what kind of fields are presented in Map and then try to use proper factory.

Comment: My problem is that I don't understand how it is possible to implement switching in Dart depending on the type of value in the key (string or Map). At first I thought to use Enum, but they can only be CONST, I couldn't put a type definition inside them. 
Then I tried inheritance from an abstract class, but getters were not available in the derived class. As a result, I came to the conclusion that it is easier to use the Dynamic type, although it is not welcome in Dart